# Reasonably priced laser cutting service in the UK?

Tags: laser

Has anyone had any experiences with laser cutting services in the UK? I've googled but most of the results seem to be for expensive industrial setups. What I'm looking for is someone who can do pretty much what the Pololu service [here](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/749) does but nearer to me to reduce shipping time and costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [RazorLAB](http://www.razorlab.co.uk/)?

Also, if you're in London, University of the Arts appears [to make its laser cutter available to external clients for a fee.](http://www.csm.arts.ac.uk/37056.htm)

I've not used -- and have no connection to -- either service.

Comment: Ooh, RazorLab looks just the ticket.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this question boils down to what you consider a reasonable rate, too? I have no experience of the going rate, are we talking a couple of quid, or £50-100? If there just isn't anyone you can find locally then maybe it's time to build your own. It's been posted before, but here's the link to the Instructable about [building your own laser cutter for less than 50 dollars](http://www.instructables.com/id/Laser-cutter-start-slicing-stuff-for-under-50-dol/), I suppose it also depends how many times you'll need to use it.

Some Secondary schools have access to laser cutters, maybe trawling through some of your local schools or colleges might throw some up. You may be able to do a deal with them, ie share some of your technological know how with them in exchange for some laser cutting, maybe a robot building session or a talk about programming to some VI Formers. What about the University of Surrey, do they not have anything?

Comment: 50-100 is reasonable. Right now I don't think building my own is my first choice, but thanks for the link. The schools angle is one that I have been thinking of as a backup plan. I like the idea of trading knowledge for cutting time ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have used Ponoko.com and they are very good. I am in the US, but I use the UK company. They are very good with their support and that is highly valuable to me!

Comment: Looks like they're US based what do you mean by "UK company"?

Comment: Ponoko is merely a front for a number of manufacturing companies. There's one in the UK, one in Germany, Italy... etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Macclesfield Laser](http://macclesfieldlaser.com/index.html).

I've not used the service, but I know the people who run the place and when I finally set up my own electronics biz I **will** be using them.

Comment: ps... tell them Mini sent you ;)